# Cmd - consultar e exportar em arquivo único. Sql

Tags: cmd, prompt

Tenho uma pasta com diversas sub-pastas contendo varios `arquivos.SQL`

Gostaria de saber se tem algum comando do `cmd` para buscar e copiar para um único arquivo todos os meus arquivos `.SQL` encontrados.

Consegui fazer isso somente exportando os nomes dos arquivos, mas não o seu conteúdo.

Comando:

```
C:\Users\jefer\Desktop\Integracao>dir /s .sql > todos_scripts.sql
```

Este comando lista todos os títulos dos arquivos encontrados. Gostaria de copiar e exportar o conteúdo dos arquivos um abaixo do outro.

Gostaria de buscar uma solução do tipo abaixo, mas usando um `dir` ou `find` e mesclando resultados para um único resultado.

Comando:

```
C:\Users\jefer\Desktop\Integracao>copy *.sql todos_scripts.sql
```

Outra coisa que pensei era unificar dois comandos, mas suponho que não é possível.

Exemplo errado:

```
dir /s .sql | copy *sql listao.sql
```

Comment: Leia o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas)

Comment: faça um `foreach` no conteúdo do arquivo gerado, assim por exemplo: `for %%f IN (todos_scripts.sql) do coloque-seu-comando-copy-aqui`, ou pq não fazez um `foreach` e já executa o comando ao invés de gerar um arquivo com os scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Tente usando `for /r` loop com `copy /b /y listao.sql+"file_in_loop" listao.sql` :

```
>nul cd.2>listao.sql & for /r "C:\Users\jefer\Desktop\Integracao" %i in (*.sql)do copy /y /b .\listao.sql+"%~i" listao.sql
```

Esses comandos concatenam todos os seus arquivos `.sql` recursivamente em um só (listao.sql) na pasta atual.

Para especificar o local onde salvar o arquivo `listao.sql`

```
>nul cd.2>"c:\pasta\salva\listao.sql" & for /r "C:\Users\jefer\Desktop\Integracao" %i in (*.sql)do copy /y /b "c:\pasta\salva\listao.sql"+"%~i" "c:\pasta\salva\listao.sql"
```

**Obs.:** Salve o seu arquivo `listao.sql` em uma pasta/sub-pasta diferente de onde o loop vai percorrer, assim evitando duplicidade de cópias acumulativa durante o processamento.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda de todos.

Comment: @JéfersonMöller Trankilo tchê, bom que funcionou

Comment: Obrigado Muito bom. Aprendi uma coisa nova.

Comment: Desculpe minha ignorancia. Como faço para colocar como resolvido e baixar esta pergunta?

Comment: Este comando que você enviou ficou muito bom. Te pergunto. Tenho a possibilidade de adaptar ele para digitar intervalo de data de modificação por arquivo ou pasta? Tipo digito data inicial e ele copia o intervalo da data inicial ate hoje.

Comment: @JéfersonMöller Tem como fazer isso sim, mas sugiro fazer outra pergunta.

Comment: @JéfersonMöller Bom dia. Conseguiu fazer alguma adaptação por data, na seleção dos arquivos?